How do I refresh a page after dispensing a file to the user?
I have the following in a method which downloads a .zip file to the user after they click a button on the front-end.
Private Sub SendZipToClient(memStream As MemoryStream)
    If memStream IsNot Nothing AndAlso memStream.Length > 0 Then
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment; filename=SomeFile.zip")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("refresh", "1")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray())
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = True
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    End If
End Sub

The file downloads, but the page does not refresh after the download is complete.
I need the page to refresh because, after the user clicks the button to generate the zip file, the page displays a message to the user that the page is doing work. Once that work is complete, the message has to go away.
I can't take a different approach to this because this isn't a fresh project - it's something that's running live right now.
What do I need to change here to make this work?

How do I refresh a page after dispensing a file to the user > You don't. A request to a server can only return 1 thing at a time. So either a zip or an updated html file, not both. You could use jquery to open the download in a new window and then update the current page async or with a full form post.
